# Add Social icon on same level as the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a navigation bar that floats the buttons on the left. I no want to add 4 social media icons but I want them to align on the right. However we i add the social media icon they are aligned on the right but not inline with the navigation bar, but just below it. adding `top:-50px;`doesnt help.

```
<body>

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>TL Custom Printing</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Custom Printing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="social">
    <a href="#" title="Follow TL Custom Printing on Twitter" alt="TL custom Print Twitter Icon"><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="Like TL Custom Printing on Facebook" alt="TL custom Print Facebook Icon"><img src="images/fb.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="Follow TL Custom Printing on Flickr" alt="TL custom Print Flickr Icon"><img src="images/flickr.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="Follow TL Custom Printing on Pinterest" alt="TL custom Print Pinterest Icon"><img src="images/pinterest.png" /></a>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Navigation Bar
----------------------------------------------- */
.menu{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    width:100%;
}

.menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    background:#2d2d2d;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.menu li{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.menu li:first-child{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ff4800;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    border-top:2px solid transparent;
}

.menu a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#bbbbbb;
    border-top:2px solid transparent;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu li.active a{
    background:#3d3d3d;
    color:#dddddd;
    border-top:2px solid #ff4800;
}

.clearFloat{
    clear:both;
}

/* Social Media Icons
----------------------------------------------- */
#social {
    float:right;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/syewF/)

Comment: jsfiddle would be nice, [images missing here](http://jsfiddle.net/EP65R/)

Comment: See if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/PZC4R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing your floats in the `.menu` div so `.menu` and `.social` will never sit on the same line. Here is one solution (of which there are many):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Y8R/)

```
<div class="menu_wrap"> <!-- ADD A WRAPPER -->
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
           <!-- REMOVE THE CLEARFIX FROM HERE -->
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="social">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div> <!--  ADD CLEARFIX HERE -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu_wrap {
    background: #000;
}
```

Also, `#social {` should be `.social {` (class not ID)

Comment: how would i go about vertically centering the images now?

Answer (score 0):

[Do You need this](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/SuprX/)

Explanation: 
  1. Set width 100% to your header/footer.

```
.header
{
  background: #333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

2. Set width to menu and social and float properties..

```
 .social 
{
 float:right;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 28%;
}
.social a img
{
  margin-top: 10px;  
}
```

There is no social id in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes in your mark up.I had put the `div` social inside the parent and had corrected the `#social` to `.social` in your css.

[WORKING CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/syewF/3/)